# How to have new activity count above any view?

Tags: views, notifications

I have seen on your website, when there is a new question posted, the list shows a new activity button with a count above the list. How can I do that in Drupal with any view?

I am interested in showing such a thing with [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses). There is an option in statuses settings to show a refresh button below the status stream when there is a new activity, but I want to show it above like on stackexchange and with a count.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module to add such notifications to any **menu item** and/or **menu tab** of your choice.

Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Provides a method for adding iOS-style badges to menu items. (see screenshot)
>
> [image]
>
> #### Adding Badges to Menus
>
> Once enabled, go to `Administration > Structure > Menus`, and click "list links" next to the menu containing the target item. Click "edit" next to the item and select the badge to display with the Display Menu Badge select box.
>
> #### Adding Badges to Tabs
>
> For adding badges to menu tabs, there is a tab under `Administration > Structure > Menus` called "Tab Menu Badges". Search for the menu router path of the tab you want to alter, then select a badge from the corresponding select box.
>
> #### Badge Types
>
> The module includes five example badges, and new badges can be created easily with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Modules can also supply their own badges with a hook implementation. See the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/menu_badges.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) file for details.

Because of how it integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you basically reduce the solution for any type of notification to something like "Just create an appropriate view of it".

#### Video tutorials:

- [Defining Menu Badges with Views in Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoZQNg5QOI), from the module maintainer, which shows how to use it for a custom view with a menu tab "unpublished content" within `admin/content`.
- [Drupal 7 Menu Badges Module](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iz25ED1ECv8).

Comment: I know how to create a menu badge, but I guess creating a badge for menu items is a different thing, whereas, my question is related to the count above the view specifically, statuses. I have already created activity log with message module and used menu badges to show the count of new activity, but there is another problem that it does not decrease the number when the menu item is clicked and activity page is visited.